# Target bean of type org.springframework.data.util.Pair is not of type of the persistent entity (com.mycompany.hibernatepoc.ConnectionManager

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a controller method that is just adding a test object to the repo, full error when I try to save is the following. The service calls a CrudRepository

Resolved [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Target bean of type org.springframework.data.util.Pair is not of type of the persistent entity (com.mycompany.hibernatepoc.ConnectionManager)!: org.springframework.data.util.Pair; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target bean of type org.springframework.data.util.Pair is not of type of the persistent entity (com.mycompany.hibernatepoc.ConnectionManager)!: org.springframework.data.util.Pair]

My controller

```
   @Controller
  public class MasterConnectionController {


@Autowired
MasterConnectionService masterConnectionService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/testAdd", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<MasterConnectionManager> testAdd() {
    DocumentValidation documentValidation1 = new DocumentValidation();
    documentValidation1.setDetails("1st validation for document 1");
    DocumentValidation documentValidation2 = new DocumentValidation();
    documentValidation2.setDetails("2nd validation for document 1");   

    ArrayList<DocumentValidation> documentValidationList = new  ArrayList<DocumentValidation>();
    documentValidationList.add(documentValidation1);
    documentValidationList.add(documentValidation2);

    DocumentDetail documentDetail1 = new DocumentDetail();
    documentDetail1.setLocation("location of document 1");
    documentDetail1.setDocumentValidationList(documentValidationList);

    ConnectionManager connectionManager1 = new ConnectionManager();
    connectionManager1.setType(ValidationType.Document);

    MasterConnectionManager master = new MasterConnectionManager();
    ArrayList<ConnectionManager> connectionManagerList = new ArrayList<ConnectionManager>();
    connectionManagerList.add(connectionManager1);
    master.setConnectionManagerList(connectionManagerList);


    return new ResponseEntity<>(masterConnectionService.save(master),HttpStatus.OK);


}
```

MasterConnectionManager

```
@Entity
public class MasterConnectionManager {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long controlId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy= "masterConnectionManager", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<ConnectionManager> connectionManagerList;

public MasterConnectionManager(){}


public MasterConnectionManager(List<ConnectionManager> connectionManagerList) {
    super();
    this.connectionManagerList = connectionManagerList;
}
```

ConnectionManager

```
  @Entity
  public class ConnectionManager {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private int sequence;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "masterConnectionManager_controlId")
private MasterConnectionManager masterConnectionManager;

public enum ValidationType {Email, Document, Sql};
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ValidationType type;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "emailDetail_id")
private EmailDetail emailDetail;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "documentDetail_id")
private DocumentDetail documentDetail;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "sqlDetail_id")
private SqlDetail sqlDetail;

public ConnectionManager(){};



public ConnectionManager(int sequence, MasterConnectionManager masterConnectionManager, ValidationType type,
        EmailDetail emailDetail, DocumentDetail documentDetail, SqlDetail sqlDetail) {
    super();
    this.sequence = sequence;
    this.masterConnectionManager = masterConnectionManager;
    this.type = type;
    this.emailDetail = emailDetail;
    this.documentDetail = documentDetail;
    this.sqlDetail = sqlDetail;
}
```

Repo

```
@Repository
 public interface MasterConnectionRepo extends CrudRepository < 
 MasterConnectionManager, Long> {

 }
```

Comment: Can you show your `Repository` definition?

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: According to this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176891/nested-data-structure-with-spring-data-jdbc) this is a bug?

Comment: Hmmmm Interesting , seems like there is nothing I can do besides redesigning my code to have less nested entities then?

Comment: Seems that way.  Sad.